# How do I create an administrator user on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts

I want to create a user having `sudo` powers in Ubuntu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

First, create the user with:

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

You can read more about this command in the man pages of your system with `man adduser`.

You can then add a user to the `sudo` group with with the command:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

Note that versions of Ubuntu until 11.10 will use `admin` as group instead of `sudo`:

> Until Ubuntu 11.10, the Unix group for administrators with root privileges through sudo had been admin. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it is now sudo, for compatibility with Debian and sudo itself. However, for backwards compatibility, admin group members are still recognized as administrators

---

If your system does not, then we need to mess with the sudoers file to grant sudo permissions. You can read about the sudoers file with `man sudoers` for details on the exact syntax and available options, but for simplicity's sake, you can do either of the following:

- Create a group with the `addgroup` command, and then add that group to the sudoers file. Use `addgroup <groupname>` to create the group, and then edit the sudoers file (`sudo visudo`) and add the line `%<groupname> ALL=(ALL) ALL` to the bottom
- Edit the sudoers file with `sudo visudo`, and add `<username> ALL=(ALL) ALL` at the bottom for each user you want to add.

Comment: I misread, thinking you had already created the user. Use `sudo adduser <username>` to create the user, and then use `sudo adduser <username> admin` to grand them sudo powers. Ex: `sudo adduser piemesons` and `sudo adduser piemesons admin`

Comment: @Darth Android adduser: The user `username' does not exist. and what about the password of that user? and its not admin group its giving him adminstrator powers

Comment: Its not admin group.. Its adminstrators power. User created. Now i want to give him adminstrator powers.?

Comment: adduser: The group `admin' does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, my ubuntu installation creates an admin group which has sudo powers. Read up on the sudoers file (`man sudoers`) and then `sudo visudo` to edit the file and grant permissions to whichever users or groups you want. You can use this file to control how sudo behaves, including whether it prompts for a password, or how long to keep a sudo session active (15min is default)

Comment: @Darth Android Yaa here is sudo visudo . I have a line "root    ALL=(ALL) ALL". i think i just need to add a another line ie:  "myNewUser ALL=(ALL) ALL". What say?

Comment: You might also try adding to the `sudo` group if it exists, or if you have to use the route suggested in my previous comment, either create a new group (`sudo addgroup <groupname>`) and then add the line `%<groupname> ALL=(ALL) ALL` to the sudoers file, or simply add individual users with `<username> ALL=(ALL) ALL` into the sudoers file.

Comment: You might want to add that if you're doing this on desktop, current LTS also puts the initial admin user in some other groups as well. adm, cdrom, sudo, dip, plugdev, lpadmin, and sambashare on a clean install with `cat /etc/group` | grep testing | cut -f 1 -d :

Answer (score 27):

The *"popular"* answer is how to *"reimplement"*, not *"how to add the user?"*. Bare minimum you need to do is this:

```
usermod -a -G sudo USERNAME
```

On my particular system, I am a member of the following groups:

```
usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare,libvirtd USERNAME
```

To verify what you have done:

```
groups USERNAME
```

Comment: I shared your question in the Ubuntu room since it is more correct.  The only thing I might add is that libvirtd is not a default group for a clean install.  The rest are.

Answer (score 3):

Choose `System` -> `Administration` -> `Users and Groups`.

Select `Add` to add your new user. When you have completed the wizard, choose your new user and click on `account type` and change from `Desktop user` to `Administrator`.

Comment: I m on server dude. Only command line :-)

Comment: On my 12.04 system you will need to log out and in again before it works. But very easy and simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable root by:

```
passwd root
```

and then insert the password for the root

Comment: This is an horrible answer. **NO ONE SHOULD EVER BE USING ROOT DIRECTLY.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are really want to create superuser (copy of root but with other password and home directory) and not a sudo user, use UID=0 and GID=0 for new user:

`useradd -ou 0 -g 0 john`

`-o` allows you to create non-unique UID (root UID=0)

`-u` $UID sets $UID

`-g` $GID sets $GID

Answer (score -3):

What I do is adding user to group called wheel, user belonging to that group can execute any administrator command using sudo.

You must enable that feature in /etc/sudoers, uncomment line below
%wheel  ALL=(ALL) ALL

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but for the benefit of people coming here now: By default in Ubuntu, no `wheel` group exists, and this is *not* how administrative abilities are conferred. The `sudo` group is used (or the `admin` group -- *not* to be confused with the other group called `adm` -- in Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier).