# How do I create a superuser from the command line in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a admin user on ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/196848/how-to-create-a-admin-user-on-ubuntu)

How can I create a superuser in Ubuntu 11.10? I need to create it using the command line.

Either we could change a normal user to become a superuser, or we could create a superuser right away.

Answer (score 10):

You can [create a new user](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto) simply using the [**`adduser(8)`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/adduser.8.html) command.

To make it a user capable of performing `sudo`, add him to the `sudo` group using either of the following commands:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo <username>
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

This works because the `sudo` group is predefined in `/etc/sudoers`. Note though that older versions of Ubuntu [will use `admin`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer) as group instead:

> Until Ubuntu 11.10, the Unix group for administrators with root privileges through sudo had been admin. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it is now sudo, for compatibility with Debian and sudo itself. However, for backwards compatibility, admin group members are still recognized as administrators

For any other customization, refer to the [Sudoers documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Comment: `adduser` can also add users to groups: `adduser <username> <groupname>`

Comment: Yeah, it's just a nice frontend, you're right :)

Comment: Also, to my understanding, there is a slight distinction between the `admin` and `sudo` groups (both exist in 11.10), but I don't think I understand it myself.

Comment: I thought it was uncommented by default in `sudoers` but I don't know exactly anymore.

Comment: This doesn't work in 12.04.2. "usermod: group 'admin' does not exist"

Comment: @Cerin If you read my answer it says that you have to use `sudo` for newer Ubuntu versions. I'll rewrite the answer later for that to be the default, but it is there...